# Check username against all users' phone number in Wordpress DB

Tags: wordpress, metadata

How can I check to see whether there is a match of the Username (that the user chooses when trying to register at `http://example.com/wp-signup.php`) and all users' phone number in the database?
If there is no match, then we let them register with that phone number.
If there is there is a match, then I would like to show the username of the user that has the phone number matches with the username (in this format 18186665555) that the user trying to register for, and ask them to login using that username, maybe also include a "forget password" in case the user forget the password for this account.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, you'll have to tweak it for yourself:

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$user_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->users where user_login = '$username';" ) );

// you can check if no rows were returned here, which means the username does not exist in database

$key = 'phone_number';
$single = true;
$user_phone = get_user_meta($user_id, $key, $single); // get his phone number assumed you are saving it during registration

?>
```